# Could not upload image using Parse Server

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I have been using Parse for a very long time. Today I installed Parse Server locally ( Using cloned repo from heroku and also using mongoDB locally ), and tried to upload an image. The Swift code i used to upload image.

```
  let testObject = PFObject(className: "Test")
        testObject["foo"] = "bar"

        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1")!)
        {
            testObject["image"] = PFFile(data: imageData)
        }

        testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if let properError = error
            {
                print(properError)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Object has been saved.")
            }
        }
```

I got this error message.

```
[Error]: Could not store file. (Code: 130, Version: 1.12.0)
Error Domain=Parse Code=130 "Could not store file." UserInfo={code=130, temporary=0, error=Could not store file., NSLocalizedDescription=Could not store file.}
```

After that i tried to upload an image to Parse.com by changing some settings in the app. By using the same code to upload image to server.
Then i got this error message.

```
 [Error]: Could not store file. (Code: 130, Version: 1.12.0)
    Error Domain=Parse Code=130 "invalid file upload" UserInfo={code=130, temporary=0, error=Could not store file., NSLocalizedDescription=invalid file upload.}
```

After that i installed Parse Server on Heroku and connected MongoLabs, and tried to upload the same file with same code, i got error message saying that "The Internet connection appears to be offline." when there is proper Internet connection.

After that i tried to upload a very small sized image to the same Parse Server hosted in Heroku, then it worked. The file uploaded and in MongoLabs. And I saw that file saved with a name "hashValue_file_bin".

I was looking for this file in project directory, but could not see it. Where i can see these kind of files ? Are they directly uploading into Database or using a directory structure.

Also please help me out why this uploading not works ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will answer your questions

[issue #136](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/136)

In short, this will be fixed about 2 days ago and will be in v2.1.3